GET Count, email, and associating values within table
I'm following up on this question.
I have a table called list_all that looks like this:
|   EMAIL     |    PROPERTY     |   ISP_GROUP    |  LAST_SENT_DATE |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| email1      |    prop1        |   gmail        |  2024-06-25     |
| email2      |    prop3        |   yahoo        |  2024-06-02     |
| email3      |    prop2        |   other        |  2024-06-15     |
| email1      |    prop5        |   gmail        |  2024-06-16     |
| email1      |    prop6        |   gmail        |  2024-06-22     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------

I can run a query like this to get a count of how many of each email exists between a certain date:
SELECT 
    COUNT(`email`) as 'EMAIL COUNT'
    , `email` 
    , `isp_group`
FROM `list_all` 
WHERE `last_sent_date` BETWEEN '2024-06-01' AND '2024-06-30'
GROUP BY `email`, `isp_group`
ORDER BY `EMAIL COUNT` DESC

This will spit out something like this:
| EMAIL COUNT    |     email      |   isp_group   |
---------------------------------------------------
|     3          |     email1     |   gmail       |
|     1          |     email2     |   yahoo       |
|     1          |     email3     |   other       |
---------------------------------------------------

I'm trying to find a way to show the PROPERTY as well but keep the total count.
Maybe there's a way to list out each property in another column, but have them all in one cell, like this:
| EMAIL COUNT    |     email      |   isp_group   |  PROPERTY   |
----------------------------------------------------------------
|     3          |     email1     |   gmail       |  p1,p2,p3   |
|     1          |     email2     |   yahoo       |     p3      |
|     1          |     email3     |   other       |     p2      |
----------------------------------------------------------------

If I can make the above happen, that would probably solve my problem.
Is this possible?

Do you want to count/to list all properties or to count/to list DISTINCT properties? Note you can add DISTINCT to GROUP_CONCAT if intended.

GROUP_CONCAT is the function you are looking for.

This function returns a string result with the concatenated non-NULL
values from a group. It returns NULL if there are no non-NULL values.
The full syntax is as follows:
GROUP_CONCAT([DISTINCT] expr [,expr ...]
             [ORDER BY {unsigned_integer | col_name | expr}
                 [ASC | DESC] [,col_name ...]]
             [SEPARATOR str_val])



Add GROUP_CONCAT(property) as property into your query
SELECT COUNT(`email`) as 'EMAIL COUNT',
       email ,
       isp_group,
       GROUP_CONCAT(property) as property
FROM `list_all` 
WHERE `last_sent_date` BETWEEN '2024-06-01' AND '2024-06-30'
GROUP BY `email`, `isp_group`
ORDER BY `EMAIL COUNT` DESC

See example
